# Can't get property from query in Neo4jClient C#

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

This is first time I try to use Neo4jClient and have no experiences.
I expected my program can print out Name of people with specific relationship has assigned in Neo4j.
I've got very simple code like:

```
    using Neo4jClient;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Neo4J.NET_Labs
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
                client.Connect();

                var query = client
                    .Cypher
                    .Match("(n)-[:LOVE]-(lover)")
                    .Return(lover => lover.As<Person>())
                                    ;
                int count = 0;
                foreach (var result in query.Results)
                {
                    count++;
                    Console.WriteLine("People {0} count {1}", result.name, count);
                }

        //Stop to show result
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string name;
}
```

}

Result of snip:

```
    People  count 1
    People  count 2
```

[image: Result of Code]

Could someone pls tell me how to get properties form query.Result.

Comment: That code should work fine. Can you run the query directly in the web-based browser (http://localhost:7474) and see if the data in your DB looks different at all?

Comment: Dear @TathamOddie, Yes, I ran the query with Cypher: "MATCH (a)-[:LOVE]-(b) RETURN a.name, b.name" and saw 2 nodes with LOVE relationship appeared. I am using Neo4j 2.0 RC1. OS win7-64 NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: Can you change your 'Name' to a property, so it should read `public string name {get;set;}` I believe Json.NET needs properties, not members to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* because of the definition of the 'Person' class, JSON.Net is unable to deserialize to members, and requires properties. You can test this by running the below code:

```
public class Person { public string Name { get;set;} }
public class PersonWithMembers { public string Name; }
```

Basically identical classes, one with a property, one with a member.

```
//Stick this in the Main method
var pA = new Person {Name = "PersonA", Twitter = "tA"};
var pB = new Person {Name = "PersonB", Twitter = "tB"};

gc.Cypher.Create("(p:Person {person})").WithParam("person", pA).ExecuteWithoutResults();
gc.Cypher.Create("(p:Person {person})").WithParam("person", pB).ExecuteWithoutResults();

Console.WriteLine("Members:");
var membersQuery = gc.Cypher
    .Match("(p:Person)")
    .Return(p => p.As<PersonWithMembers>());

foreach (var p in membersQuery.Results)
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);

Console.WriteLine("Properties:");
var propertiesQuery = gc.Cypher
    .Match("(p:Person)")
    .Return(p => p.As<Person>());

foreach (var p in propertiesQuery.Results)
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
```

You should get the output:

```
Members:


Properties:
PersonA
PersonB
```

Comment: Ah. Good catch! I so rarely use public fields for anything, so this didn't even cross my mind. This has come up once before. If it comes up again, I might add a "hey, you have 0 properties on this type, do you want to try writing that code again?" exception.

Comment: Heh, that'd be a great exception to see pop up :)